# Multivariable Polar Limits

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

In my Calc 3 class we reviewed limits and my teacher said that you can only use polar when you are going to $(0,0).$ When we have something like $\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ I saw that this was always $\frac{1}{2}$ however since we cannot check along the infinitely many paths we use polar, but this is to the point $(1,1)$, not $(0,0)$ so I rewrote the limit as $\lim_{(r,\theta)\to (\sqrt{2},\frac{\pi}{4})}\frac{r^2\cos \theta \sin \theta}{r^2(\cos^2 \theta +\sin^2 \theta)}=\frac{1}{2}$ so I have proved this limit to be $\frac{1}{2},$ would this work every time if I convert the point to polar and then you evaluate the limit? My teacher said only when you go to the origin it works but In the example I showed we weren't going to the origin but I still got the answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think there has been a lot of confusion here.  If $f$ is continuous then the limit of $f$ is just $f$ at that point.  What coordinate system you use has nothing to do with the existence of a limit.  For multivariable functions proving that a limit exists is a pain.  The general way involves using the epsilon delta limit definition but that is quite annoying.  On the other hand it's usually easy to show a limit doesn't exist by finding two paths that give different limits.  Ex, using your function as it goes to (0,0) the limit doesn't exist.  Consider $y=x$ and $y=2x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute a limit near the point $(a,b)$ using polar coordinates, you have to put

$$x=a+r\cos(\theta), \;y=b+r\sin(\theta)$$
which are the parametric equations of a circle arround the point $(a,b)$.

we get the  limit when $r \to 0$ if the result  doesn't depend on $\theta$.